# Efficiently iterating through a cvMat image

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, memory, mat

I am trying to iterate through a number of images and compare the pixel values to those of corresponding ground truth images.  When doing this, however, my computer's memory usage increases very quickly and eventually the program crashes and I get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 259200 bytes) in unknown function, file C:\OpenCV2.3\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52
```

The main approaches I have tried are below.  Am I missing something that's causing this to happen and is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Approach 1:

```
void calculateMetrics(cv::Mat gt_frame, cv::Mat result_frame){

    rows = result_frame.rows;
    cols = result_frame.cols;

    int gt;
    int res;

    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++){

            gt = gt_frame.at<uchar>(i, j);
            res = result_frame.at<uchar>(i, j);

            if((gt == 255) && (res == 255))     // True positive
                tp++;
            else if((gt == 0) && (res == 0))    // True negative
                tn++;
            else if((gt == 0) && (res == 255))  // False positive
                fp++;
            else if((gt == 255) && (res == 0))  // False negative
                fn++;
        }
    }
}
```

Approach 2:

```
void calculateMetrics(cv::Mat gt_frame, cv::Mat result_frame){

    rows = result_frame.rows;
    cols = result_frame.cols;

    uchar *gt;
    uchar *res;

    for(i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
        gt = gt_frame.ptr(i);
        res = result_frame.ptr(i);

        for(j = 0; j < cols; ++j){
            *gt++;
            *res++;

            if((*gt == 255) && (*res == 255))       // True positive
                tp++;
            else if((*gt == 0) && (*res == 0))  // True negative
                tn++;
            else if((*gt == 0) && (*res == 255))    // False positive
                fp++;
            else if((*gt == 255) && (*res == 0))    // False negative
                fn++;
       }
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
void EvaluationFramework::processResults(int video_num){
    num_frames = getNumFrames(video_num);

    for(j = 0; j < num_frames; j++){

        gt_frame = getGroundTruthFrame(video_num, j);
        result_frame = getResultFrame(video_num, j);

        calculateMetrics(gt_frame, result_frame);
    }

    std::cout << "TP: " << tp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TN: " << tn << std::endl;
    std::cout << "FP: " << fp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "FN: " << fn << std::endl;

    precision = getPrecision((double)tp, (double)fp);
    recall = getRecall((double)tp, (double)fn);
    fmeasure = getFmeasure(precision, recall);

    std::cout << "Precision: " << precision << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Recall: " << recall << std::endl;
    std::cout << "F-Measure: " << fmeasure << std::endl;

    insertResults(0, video_num, precision, recall, fmeasure);
}
```

The getGroundTruthFrame and getResultFrame functions simply read the relevant images from a folder, getPrecision, getRecall and getFmeasure perform fairly simple calculations and insertResults inserts the calculated values into a database.

Comment: There's no obvious leak, but why are you passing by value instead of by reference - e.g. `void calculateMetrics(cv::Mat &gt_frame, cv::Mat &result_frame)`? Can you show the code that calls this function too?

Comment: @RogerRowland I've added the calling code in above.  As for passing by reference rather than value, to be honest I just hadn't thought of doing it that way.  What's the benefit of passing them by reference?

Comment: Problem is probably in getNumFrames(), getGroundTruthFrame() or getResultFrame(), or even insertResults(), can you show us the code?

Comment: Although `cv::Mat` uses reference counting for copy, assignment etc., so there's no temporary copies of pixel data being made when you pass by value, it's usually a good habit to get in to to pass complex objects (i.e. class instances) by reference or by `const` reference instead of by value in order to minimise unnecessary creation of temporary copies. You seem to be leaking memory and this is therefore an area that falls under suspicion. Without reviewing *all* of your code, it's not possible to track it down precisely but if using pass-by-reference changes or fixes the leak, it gives a clue